# Issue with two-way binding inside dom-repeat in Polymer 1.0

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a simple `template` like this

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[items]]">
    <paper-button active="{{item.selected}}" toggles raised>
        <span>[[item.selected]]</span>
    </paper-button>
</template>
```

If I activate the first `paper-button` in the list by tapping it and then call

`this.set('items.0.selected', !this.items[0].selected);`

It gets deactivated.

But then if I try the exact steps above again, the button doesn't get deactivated, which makes the button state and the `selected` value out of sync.

Why is it doing this? The issue can be replicated over [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/FE016PvKffbS4sWb29Ia?p=preview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. So I tried to use a single `paper-button` binding to a single `item` instance and it turned out to be working fine, which got me thinking that it might have something to do with path binding inside an array.

So I then added a `tap` handler to the `paper-button` and every time it's tapped, do a `notifyPath` on the `selected` subproperty path with the value of itself -

```
this.notifyPath('items.0.selected', this.items[0].selected);
```

And [it](http://plnkr.co/edit/n1heAd1u6WSkYiFpgRuF?p=preview) works.